# How to create a frequency table in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

If i have data like

```
Col1 
A
B
A
B
A
C
```

I need output like

```
Col_value          Count
A                  3   
B                  2
C                  1
```

I need to col_value and count be column names.
So I can access it like a['col_value']

Answer (score 10):

Use `value_counts`:

```
df = pd.value_counts(df.Col1).to_frame().reset_index()
df
A    3
B    2
C    1
```

then rename your columns if needed:

```
df.columns = ['Col_value','Count']

df
  Col_value  Count
0         A      3
1         B      2
2         C      1
```

Comment: but value_counts doesn't provide data frame as output

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Col1')
       .size()
       .reset_index(name='Count')
       .rename(columns={'Col1':'Col_value'})
print (df)
  Col_value  Count
0         A      3
1         B      2
2         C      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.crosstab` as another alternative:

```
import pandas as pd

help(pd.crosstab)
```

Help on function `crosstab` in module `pandas.core.reshape.pivot`:

```
crosstab(index, columns, values=None, rownames=None, colnames=None, aggfunc=None, margins=False, margins_name='All', dropna=True, normalize=False)
```

Example:

```
df_freq = pd.crosstab(df['Col1'], columns='count')

df_freq.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def frequencyTable(alist):
'''
list -> chart 

Returns None. Side effect is printing two columns showing each number that
is in the list, and then a column indicating how many times it was in the list.

Example:

>>> frequencyTable([1, 3, 3, 2])
ITEM FREQUENCY
1     1
2     1
3     2

'''
    countdict = {}

    for item in alist:
        if item in countdict:
            countdict[item] = countdict[item] + 1
        else:
            countdict[item] = 1
    itemlist = list(countdict.keys())
    itemlist.sort()

    print("ITEM", "FREQUENCY")

    for item in itemlist:
        print(item, "   ", countdict[item])

    return None
```